# jooq deserialize a polymorphic class

Tags: deserialization, jooq, fasterxml

I am using JOOQ to manipulate the database，now i have a problem.
There is a polymorphic class OrderEntry

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ReissueOrderEntry.class, name = "reissue"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RawOrderEntry.class, name = "raw"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FreebieOrderEntry.class, name = "freebie"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ReplaceOrderEntry.class, name = "replace")
})
public class OrderEntry extends OrderObject {
    String type;
}
```

It will be deserialized into different objects according to the field 'type'.
But in jooq's deserialization it will only be deserialized as OrderEntry.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izlIk.png.)

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to use the built-in [`ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/) logic that makes use of Jackson, e.g. when writing things like:

```java
record.into(OrderEntry.class);
```

jOOQ loads Jackson from the classpath without any additional modules / plugins loaded. If you wish to use additional plugins, then you'll have to roll your own  [`ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/), which implements loading additional plugins.